# Using IComparable in list<T> with different inheritance related types of T

Tags: c#, interface, polymorphism, base-class, generic-collections

Just some sample classes here. I try to use polymorphism in gerneric Lists, so I want each list to use its own CompareTo-Method. I don't want to find a different class arrangement. I want to understand why that is not working.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<Animal> MyAnimals = new List<Animal>();
        MyAnimals.Add(new Dog() { Name = "karl", Number = 1 });
        MyAnimals.Add(new Dog() { Name = "carla", Number = 2 });
        MyAnimals.Add(new Dog() { Name = "loki", Number = 3 });
        MyAnimals.Add(new Cat() { Name = "karsten", Size = 3 });
        MyAnimals.Add(new Cat() { Name = "charlie", Size = 5 });
        MyAnimals.Add(new Cat() { Name = "mona", Size = 1 });
        MyAnimals.Add(new Cat() { Name = "sisi", Size = 2 });
        MyAnimals.Sort();
        ShowList(MyAnimals);
        List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
        List<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>();

        foreach (var item in MyAnimals)
        {
            if (item is Cat)
                cats.Add(item as Cat);
            if (item is Dog)
                dogs.Add(item as Dog);
        }

        dogs.Reverse();
        dogs.Sort();
        cats.Sort();
        ShowList(dogs);
        ShowList(cats);

        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    private static void ShowList<T>(List<T> MyAnimals)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List of "+MyAnimals[0].GetType().Name);
        foreach (var item in MyAnimals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}

abstract class Animal  : IComparable{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        Animal animal = obj as Animal;
        if (animal != null)
            return this.Name.CompareTo(animal.Name);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Animal");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
class Dog : Animal, IComparable
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "\tNumber:"+ Number + "\n";
    }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        if (obj is Dog animal)
            if (this.Number.CompareTo(animal.Number) == 0)
            {
                return this.Name.CompareTo(animal.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.Number.CompareTo(animal.Number);
            }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Dog");

    }
}

class Cat : Animal, IComparable
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "\tNumber:" + Size + "\n";
    }

    public new int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        if (obj is Cat animal)
            if (this.Size.CompareTo(animal.Size) == 0)
            {
                return this.Name.CompareTo(animal.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.Size.CompareTo(animal.Size);
            }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a Cat");

    }
}
```

Why is `MyAnimals.Sort()` not using the `CompareTo()` in Animal class? Is there a way to use polymorhpism as it is meant to be? So that List of Animals is Compared by AnimalMethod and Dogs List by Dogs CompareTo Method and so on?

Comment: Why are you implementing `CompareTo` in `Cat` and `Dog` if you want it to use the method in `Animal`?

Comment: becuase it's always using `IComparable.CompareTo`

Comment: @Xerillio: I want to have them sorted by the type of list.

Comment: @Selvin: Is there a way to achive my goal?

Comment: provide argumen to `MyAnimals.Sort` call

Comment: It will use the comparer defined on the item's actual type, not the type defined for the items by the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Dog` and `Cat` classes have a `CompareTo` method that ***hides*** the base-class method, and because `Sort` will use the `ComapareTo` method of the item's actual type instead of the type defined for the items on the `List<T>`, you will get an exception when trying to compare a `Dog` with a `Cat`.

One way to resolve this is to implement the `IComparable<T>` interface instead, so that we specify the exact type we want to compare an object with. This way, the correct implementation will be used by the `Sort` method.

Also note that instead of re-implementing the `CompareTo` method of `Animal` (which compares the `Name` properties) for each derived class, we can simply call `base.CompareTo(other)` from the derived class's `CompareTo` method when necessary:

```
abstract class Animal : IComparable<Animal>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Animal other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        return string.Compare(Name, other.Name);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

class Dog : Animal, IComparable<Dog>
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "\tNumber:" + Number + "\n";
    }

    public int CompareTo(Dog other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        var numberCompare = Number.CompareTo(other.Number);
        return numberCompare == 0 ? base.CompareTo(other) : numberCompare;
    }
}

class Cat : Animal, IComparable<Cat>
{
    public int Size { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + "\tNumber:" + Size + "\n";
    }

    public int CompareTo(Cat other)
    {
        if (other == null) return 1;
        var sizeCompare = Size.CompareTo(other.Size);
        return sizeCompare == 0 ? base.CompareTo(other) : sizeCompare;
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to change your `ShowList` method to show the type `T` rather then the derived type of the first element in the list (otherwise the `List<Animal>` displays that it's a `List<Dog>` because the first item is a `Dog`):

```
private static void ShowList<T>(List<T> MyAnimals)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List of " + typeof(T).Name);

    foreach (var item in MyAnimals)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `IComparable` for sorting a list. The `CompareTo` method being called is always going to be the one defined on the type of the object itself and not on the type you defined for the list. Because `Cat` and `Dog` are overriding the `CompareTo` the `Sort` method is therefore never gonna use the `CompareTo` in `Animal`.

What you could do instead is use the overload `public void Sort (Comparison<T> comparison)`:

```
private int CompareAnimals(Animal animA, Animal animB)
{
    // ... your logic to compare two Animals
}

private int CompareCats(Cat catA, Cat catB)
{
    // ... your logic to compare two Cats
}

private int CompareDogs(Dog dogA, Dog dogB)
{
    // ... your logic to compare two Dogs
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Animal> MyAnimals = new List<Animal>();
    // Adding animals...
    MyAnimals.Sort(CompareAnimals);
    // ...
    dogs.Sort(CompareDogs);
    cats.Sort(CompareCats);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i just did this with static methods and added them to the suiting cat/dog class.